# little bug with ui-view

Tags: angularjs, uiview

I have the following bug when using ui-view.

on my index page I have something which looks like this:

```
<body role="document" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-include="'./views/home.html'"></div>
   //scripts
</body>
```

So far so good, it loads the partial as expected, the partial looks like this:

```
<navigation></navigation>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <sidebar></sidebar>
      <div ui-view></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Still good, sidebar and navigation are directives, they are loading perfect, and my route looks like this:

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
 $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
     url: '/',
     templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html' 
   });
 });
```

Problem is: where I go to the url on my home page '/', it does not show the dashboard.html, it display only the home.html template, so I have to add it '/#/' to display the dashboard, and after clicking it again the same link '/#/', the dashboard hides, so I have to manual type it on the url to see it again.

Have anyone having the same problem?

I'm using the last version on angular.

**UPDATE**

If I move all the logic into home.html to the index page and call it directly without using the ng-include, it works like charm, however, this is not what I need, I think there some issues with the loading that I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh - I didn't see that you had the ui-view in the partial page. That is probably not supported. You should be able to achieve your functionality by using parallel views and nested views in the ui-router. I think you just need to spend some time with the examples provided by ui-router and you should be able to achieve your functionality!

Answer (score 0):

the "otherwise" functionality is not kicking in. you should use that to provide which state should be loaded and not duplicate the state definition. I think you code should read

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
```

or

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");
```

Comment: yeah that was my first thought, I just updated as I'm using it, and I still have the same issue

Comment: what browser is this in ?